# Avoid memory leaks with strings

Tags: c#, string, memory-leaks

I've found a memory leak in my parser. I don't know how to fix that problem.
Let's see that basic routing.

```
    private void parsePage() {
        String[] tmp = null;

        foreach (String row in rows) {
            tmp = row.Split(new []{" "}, StringSplitOptions.None);

            PrivateRow t = new PrivateRow();

            t.Field1 = tmp[1];
            t.Field2 = tmp[2];
            t.Field3 = tmp[3];
            t.Field4 = String.Join(" ", tmp);

            myBigCollection.Add(t);
        }
    }


    private void parseFromFile() {
        String[] tmp = null;

        foreach (String row in rows) {
            PrivateRow t = new PrivateRow();

            t.Field1 = "mystring1";
            t.Field2 = "mystring2222";
            t.Field3 = "mystring3333";
            t.Field4 = "mystring1 xxx yy zzz";

            myBigCollection.Add(t);
        }
    }
```

Launching **parsePage()**, on a collection (rows is a List of 100000 elements) make my app grown from 20MB to 70MB.

Launching **parseFromFile()**, that read SAME collection from file, but avoiding split/join, take about 1MB.

Using a MemoryProfiler, I see that **"t" fields and PrivateRow**, kkep reference to String.Split() array and Split.Join.
I suppose that's because I assign a reference, not a copy, that can be garbage collected.

Ok, use 70mb isn't a big deal, but when I launch on production, with a lot o site, it can raise 2.5-3GB...

Cheers

Comment: You don't have a memory leak; you just have a program using some memory.  Just leave it alone and let the GC do its job.

Comment: You mention parsePage is running on the same collection as parseFromFile. But are they both loaded from a file?

Comment: parsePage parse some HTML page and put the elements in a collection, that must be in RAM for fast viewing/editing. When program is closing, the collection is serialized to disk using Protobuf. When program is opening, collection will be deserialized. I don't know why parsing 100000 elements take about 70MB in RAM. Save those on disk take about 5MB, than derialized it from disk take 30mb on RAM. The elements are the same

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a memory leak per se.  It's actually behaving properly.  The reason your second function uses so much less memory, is simply because you only have four strings in use.  Each of these four strings is allocated only once, and subsequent uses of the strings for new t.Fieldx instances actually refer to the same string values. Strings are immutable, so if you refer to the same string value more than once, it can be handled by the same string instances. See the paragraph labelled "Interning" at [this article on String in .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/strings.aspx) for some more detail on this.

In your first function, you have what are probably mostly different strings for each field, and each time through the loop.  That simply is much more varied data.  The fact that those strings are held on to is what you *want* to have happen for as long as your PrivateRow objects exist.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the references seen by the OP aren't references "to the String.Split() array" itself, though they might be references to elements within that array. Further, depending on how the code is being run, GC behaviour will be different: it's a lot less aggressive in a Debug build than in Release.

Comment: My confusion born reading that: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Tutorial+1+-+Getting+Started+with+dotMemory. The paragraph regard "Retention".

Comment: Ok, maybe isn't a memoryleak, but I don't know why serialize/deserialize list from disk, have at least half of RAM allocated. Using a profiler, parsing page, it show me a lot o Join/Split reference. Obviously deserializing file, those method aren't present, so less RAM is needed. Calling GC doesn't resolve the problem (only 2-3 Mb)

Comment: @Kaiser69, understood. That's a helpful article, but one thing to keep in mind is that this tool exists to show you how memory is used. The fact that is shows memory in use is not by definition a bad thing. The question is whether the memory in use should be in use. In your case, for as long as your PrivateRow objects are 'alive', it's appropriate for memory to be in use.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a memory leak at all, it's just garbage collector takes time to process it.

> I suppose that's because I assign a reference, not a copy, that can
>   be garbage collected.

That is not correct assumption. `string` during assignment is copied, even if it is a reference type. It is special, kind of, unique type inside BCL.

Now what about possible solution, in case you have intensive memory pressure. If you have massive amount of string to process from file, you may look on 2 options.

1) Process them in sequence, by reading a srteam (not load all at once). Loading as less data in memory as possible/required/makes sence.

2) Use [MemoryMappedFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(v=vs.110).aspx) to, again, load only chunks of data and process them in sequence.

2nd can be combined with 1st.

Comment: Yep, I evaluated your solution, but I cannot use those object. I read from and HttpStream, keep the object in RAM (for fast editing/view), than save that when app close.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, there is no evidence of a memory leak here, just delayed garbage collection.  All memory should be cleaned up eventually.

That being said, there are a couple things you can do to help keep memory usage lower or recover it more quickly:

1)You should be able to replace

```
t.Field4 = String.Join(" ", tmp);
```

with

```
t.Field4 = row;
```

You created `tmp` by splitting `row`, then you're joining it back together.  Avoid creating a new string by just using `row`.

2) Call `GC.Collect();` at the end of the method to request immediate garbage collection.  This won't reduce the memory used within the method, but it should free up memory more quickly.

Comment: The last assignment is just a way to reproduce the "bug", in production stage, Field4 is a join of last 3 item of splitted string :)

Answer (score -5):

If your application is memory-usage critical and there is a lot of repeating data you should replace string values with Enums.

Comment: You can't replace arbitrary string data with enums. Since the question is about a parser, I think it's safe to assume that string data is critical.